# mui data grid table editing cell is not working on tablet mode

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-datatable

I can edit the quantity cell on both responsive mode and phone sizes but the editable mode does not work on tablet mode. I cannot understand because of why occur and how I can fix that. Can someone help me, please? Thanks in advance.[image: datagrid]

[image: react]

[image: ui]